# Is there anything like APP_INITIALIZER for lazy loaded modules in Angular?

Tags: angular

I am looking for something that lets me execute code when a certain module is initialized. This module is lazy loaded in my application. The APP_INITIALIZER only works for the app initialization process (once at beginning starting at the main module that is bootstrapped).

I cannot use the constructor of the lazy loaded module since my service returns a Promise and I need the response synchronously for working in this lazy loaded module.

Comment: Maybe you can try Angular `resolver`. Helpful links:
https://codeburst.io/understanding-resolvers-in-angular-736e9db71267; 
https://alligator.io/angular/route-resolvers/

Answer (score 4):

Use a resolver. Resolvers are perfect for what you need.

Comment: This is great to use on component level. Is there something similar to use on module level?

Comment: @PhilippEscher One workaround you could use would be to have a module landing view that would use a resolver, it would load all the module level settings and redirect to the requested view.

Comment: @PhilippEscher Another idea is to use a module level constructor: https://www.bennadel.com/blog/3180-ngmodule-constructors-provide-a-module-level-run-block-in-angular-2-1-1.htm I have not used this but it looks like a promising workaround.